# Using SSH pubkey with multiple certificates

Tags: ssh, security, certificate, client-certificate

I am using an SSH public key to connect to a number of servers. The servers use an SSH CA to manage authorized users. The basic concept is described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu

So next to my usual `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files, I also have an `id_rsa-cert.pub` file which contains the certificate. All of this works pretty well, I can immediately log in to new machines that are configured to trust the CA key that was used to sign my key.

However, I now got my key signed by a different CA for a different set of machines. The question is now, how can I tell SSH that there are now two certificates for this key. From the documentation there seems to be no way to specify a second certificate file:

```
ssh(1) will try to load certificate information from the filename
obtained by appending -cert.pub to the path of a specified IdentityFile.
```

Simply appending the new certificate to this file (like you would do for `authorized_keys`) does not work either. In that case, SSH will still only recognize the first certificate and ignore the rest of the file.

Does anyone know how to tell SSH that I have a second certificate for this key?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use the same private key and `ssh` will use the key name to guess the certificate name, copy your private and public key:

```
cp ~.ssh/id_rsa id_rsa_group2
cp ~.ssh/id_rsa.pub id_rsa_group2.pub # probably not necessary
```

Then make the name of the certificate match, it should be `id_rsa_group2-cert.pub`

Test it : `ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa_group2 ip_of_your_server`

Then make the key selection automatic by editing `~/.ssh/config`

```
# For your first certificate:
Host a
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# For your new certificate
Host b
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_group2
```

Comment: I gotta try this out.Do you know if this requires me to add my private key two times to ssh-agent or will it realize that it is the same key for both identities?

Comment: I have found something interesting, but different enough for posting another answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CertificateFile` configuration option for that purpose, either on the command line : `ssh -o CertificateFile=~/.ssh/second_certificate.pub host_b` or by setting it into the config file (`~/.ssh/config`).

```
Host host_b
    CertificateFile ~/.ssh/second_certificate.pub
```

Since in both cases, the same certificate is used, it should work well with your `ssh-agent`.

Comment: I think I spotted a typo. There is an extra back-tick character after `CertficateFile `

Comment: Thank you @ErikSjölund, typo fixed!

Comment: I meant remove the back-tick. (My previous comment was a bit unclear)